# Getting literal markup of XML elements

Tags: javascript, xml

In an HTML document have an XML structure from an AJAX request. I would like to display it using custom syntax highlighting. For this I need the **markup of the XML tags as they appear in the loaded file**, i.e. retaining unnecessary spaces etc. The data is clearly stored in the structure, as seen in each element's parent's `innerHTML` property. But how can I elegantly retrieve it from a given XML element node? I could use something like `Elt.outerHTML.split(Elt.innerHTML)`, but that is clumsy and not totally conforming to the standard.

Is there a better way to do this? Until now I have been using my own very crude XML parser, but I want to get away from that.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the XMLSpectrum syntax highlighting tool from Qutoric (Phil Fearon - @pgfearo). We used it to good effect in the W3C XSLT 3.0 specification.

http://qutoric.com/xmlspectrum/